# ¿Como puedo validar un inicio de sesion usando HTML y una placa ARDUINO?

Tags: html, arduino

Nos mandaron en la universidad a hacer un pequeño "Web Server" con inicio de sesion y que redirija a una pagina principal en donde se va a ser una simulacion de un servidor FTP. La verdad que estoy demasiado perdido con C y con el arduino. Ando muy frustrado, ya que intente hacer un login normal como lo suelo hacer con HTML y PHP pero resulta ser que el arduino no me reconoce el script de PHP.

Segui el tutorial de esta pagina web https://startingelectronics.org/tutorials/arduino/ethernet-shield-web-server-tutorial/SD-card-web-server/

Hasta ahora solamente puedo mostrar la primera pagina del login, pero mas alla de eso nada!

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <SD.h>

// MAC address from Ethernet shield sticker under board
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 117); // IP address, may need to change depending on network
EthernetServer server(80);  // create a server at port 80
String creds = "";
File webFile;

void setup()
{
    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);  // initialize Ethernet device
    server.begin();           // start to listen for clients
    Serial.begin(9600);       // for debugging

    // initialize SD card
    Serial.println("Initializing SD card...");
    if (!SD.begin(4)) {
        Serial.println("ERROR - SD card initialization failed!");
        return;    // init failed
    }
    Serial.println("SUCCESS - SD card initialized.");
    // check for index.htm file
    if (!SD.exists("Web/index.htm")) {
        Serial.println("ERROR - Can't find index.htm file!");
        return;  // can't find index file
    }
    Serial.println("SUCCESS - Found index.htm file.");
}

void loop()
{
    EthernetClient client = server.available();  // try to get client

    if (client) {  // got client?
        boolean currentLineIsBlank = true;
        while (client.connected()) {
            if (client.available()) {   // client data available to read
                char c = client.read(); // read 1 byte (character) from client
                // last line of client request is blank and ends with \n
                // respond to client only after last line received

                if (c == '\n' && currentLineIsBlank) {
                    // send a standard http response header
                    client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
                    client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
                    client.println("Connection: close");
                    client.println();
                    // send web page
                    webFile = SD.open("Web/index.htm");        // open web page file
                    if (webFile) {
                        while(webFile.available()) {
                            client.write(webFile.read()); // send web page to client
                        }
                        webFile.close();
                    }
                    break;
                }
                // every line of text received from the client ends with \r\n
                if (c == '\n') {
                    // last character on line of received text
                    // starting new line with next character read
                    currentLineIsBlank = true;
                } 
                else if (c != '\r') {
                    // a text character was received from client
                    currentLineIsBlank = false;
                }
            } // end if (client.available())
        } // end while (client.connected())
        delay(1);      // give the web browser time to receive the data
        client.stop(); // close the connection
    } // end if (client)
}
```

Si entran a la pagina van a darse cuenta que el codigo que tengo no cambio absolutamente casi nada. Lo que intente yo hacer primero era sacar las variables de la seccion "referer" obtenidas por el metodo GET:

```
c = client.read();
Serial.print(c);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero... mis esfuerzos se fueron, ya que no pude lograrlo. ¿Como podria yo entonces hacer una pagina de login y que me redirija a la siguiente pagina?

Answer (score 0):

Queria ponerte un comentario en lugar de una respuesta, pero no me deja ya que no tengo 50 de reputación y no me deja poner comentarios. Sería conveniente que si has tratado de buscar por "Referer" pegaras el código para poder revisarlo. Si lo que quieres es buscar el apartado "Referer", deberás ir "almacenando" la petición del cliente bien en un array bien en un String (cuidado con el tamaño de los mismos ya que dependiendo de la tarjeta Arduino que estés utilizando podrías quedarte sin memoria rápidamente) para, posteriormente, buscar lo que necesitas o tratar de buscar la secuencia "Referer" y almacenar posteriormente la url.

No puedo probar el código que te voy a poner ya que no dispongo de un tarjeta Ethernet en estos momentos, pero al menos espero que te sirva de guía:

```
void loop()
{
    EthernetClient client = server.available();  // try to get client

    if (client) {  // got client?

        boolean currentLineIsBlank = true;

        //Necesitamos encontrar la secuencia Referer: ht....
        //Terminamos en 'espacio'. El siguiente caracter será el h de http...
        char referer[] = "Referer: ";
        unsigned char index = 0;
        boolean isRefererFound = false;
        String url ="";

        while (client.connected()) {
            if (client.available()) {   // client data available to read
                char c = client.read(); // read 1 byte (character) from client
                // last line of client request is blank and ends with \n
                // respond to client only after last line received

                if (c == '\n' && currentLineIsBlank) {
                    // send a standard http response header
                    client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
                    client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
                    client.println("Connection: close");
                    client.println();

                    //Si hemos encontrado la cadena Referer, deberíamos procesar la URL para encontrar
                    //usuario y contraseña. Lo ideal sería crear una función independiente.

                    boolean userFound = processUrl(url);

                    // send web page

                    if(userFound){
                      webFile = SD.open("Web/index.htm");        // open web page file
                    }
                    else{
                      webFile = SD.open("Web/login.html");
                    }

                    if (webFile) {
                        while(webFile.available()) {
                            client.write(webFile.read()); // send web page to client
                        }
                        webFile.close();
                    }
                    break;
                }
                // every line of text received from the client ends with \r\n
                if (c == '\n') {
                    // last character on line of received text
                    // starting new line with next character read
                    currentLineIsBlank = true;
                    if (isRefererFound) isRefererFound = false;
                    index = 0;
                } 
                else if (c != '\r') {
                    // a text character was received from client
                    currentLineIsBlank = false;

                    // Buscamos la secuencia Referer: en la petición
                    if( isRefererFound) {
                      //Si hemos encontrado la línea Referer, guardamos la URL de petición
                      url += c;
                    }
                    else{
                      if( c == referer[i]){ 
                         index++;
                         if( index == 9) isRefererFound = true;
                      }
                      else{
                         index = 0
                      }
                    }
              }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

El pseudo-código de la función para procesar la url podría ser:

```
boolean processUrl (String url){
    //Definir el usuario y la contraseña que vamos a buscar

    //buscar en la url el caracter ?, es donde empiezan los query params,
    //dividir la url por el caracter &
    //comparar cada división con el valor que queremos buscar

    //devolver si ha sido encontrado o no
}
```

Como te digo, no puedo probar el código, pero espero que pueda servirte de guía.

Answer (score 0):

yo tengo una función que te puede servir mira:
En esta yo busco un valor y lo hago integer.
saludos.

```
int httpRequest() {
  if (cliente.connect(server, 80)) {
    Serial.println("Conectado");
    cliente.print("GET /test/read/lectura_arduino_s.php?linea=6");  //DONDE SE ALMACENA LA FUNCION  
// -AQUI BUSCARIAS TU USUARIO Y CONTRASEÑA
    cliente.println(" HTTP/1.0");
    cliente.println("User-Agent: arduino-ethernet");
    cliente.println("Connection: close");
    cliente.println();
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("Con_mlaread");     //POR SI FALLA
    Serial.println("error_leer");
    cliente.stop();
  }
  delay(500);
  while (cliente.available()) {         //TOMA EL WEBSITE CUANDO SE CONECTA
    char c = cliente.read();        //AQUI SE LLENA
    codigo += c;
    fin = true;
  }
  if (fin) {
    int longitud = codigo.length();
    int posicion = codigo.indexOf("valor=");   //SE BUSCA UN VALOR CON DESCRIPCION "VALOR=00;"
    nombre = "";
    for (int i = posicion + 6; i < longitud; i ++) {
      if (codigo[i] == ';') i = longitud;
      else nombre += codigo[i];
    }
    fin = false;
    //Serial.println(nombre.toFloat());           //AQUI imprimo lo que leo
    //client.stop();
  }
  codigo = "";
  Serial.print(limit);
  Serial.println(temp_i);
  return nombre.toFloat();               //AQUI NACE limit PARA LOS RELAYS ;)
}
```

Comment: podrías explicar un poco mas tu código por favor :)